# What is considered defaults for celery's app.conf.humanize(with_defaults=False)?

Tags: celery, celeryd

I'm trying to printout celery's configuration using `app.conf.humanize(with_defaults=False)` following the example in the [user guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/application.html#censored-configuration). But I always get an empty string when using `with_defaults=False`, I know that the configuration changes are in effects because I can see the changes using `.humanize(with_defaults=True)` instead.

I'm guessing that adding configuration with `app.conf.config_from_object('myconfig')` is loading the configuration settings as "defaults", so **is there a way to load the config at module `myconfig` in a way that is not a default?**

This is  my source code:

```
#myconfig.py
worker_redirect_stdouts_level='INFO'
imports = ('tasks',)
```

and

```
#tasks.py
from celery import Celery

app = Celery()
app.config_from_object('myconfig')    
print "config: %s" % app.conf.humanize(with_defaults=False)

@app.task
def debug(*args, **kwargs):
    print "debug task args  : %r" % (args,)
    print "debug task kwargs: %r" % (kwargs,)
```

I start celery using `env PYTHONPATH=. celery  worker --loglevel=INFO` and it prints `config:`  (if I change to `with_defaults=True` I get the expected full output).

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3652) , since it seems that `humanize()` works as expected after accessing one item of the conf `app.conf['worker_redirect_stdouts_level']`

Answer (score 1):

The configuration loaded with `config_from_object()` or `config_from_envvar()` is not considered defaults.

The behaviour observed was due a bug fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/cefd84a4f362e983a76c781d9b661c81e563dd7e) in response to my [bug report](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3652) so future versions of celery will work as expected.

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery
app.config_from_object('myconfig')
app.conf.humanize()  # returns only settings directly set by 'myconfig' omitting  defaults
```

where `myconfig` is  a python module in the `PYTHONPATH`:

```
#myconfig.py
worker_redirect_stdouts_level='DEBUG'
```